# How to integrate vcpkg in linux with cross build toolchain, as well as sysroot?

Tags: linux, cmake, vcpkg

My question is, how to integrate vcpkg in linux with cross build toolchain, as well as sysroot?
example:

- build machine is `fedora30`
- cross build toolchain is `x86_64-centos7-gnu`

from https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg quickstart says:

```sh
> git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg.git
> cd vcpkg

PS> .\bootstrap-vcpkg.bat
Linux:~/$ ./bootstrap-vcpkg.sh
```

On my machine I have gcc 9.1 installed which is detected by `vcpkg`'s bootstrap.sh and work fine;

Meanwhile, I built a toolchain for crossbuilding, which sits in `$HOME/cross/x64_86-centos7-linux-gnu/`

How can I setup another `vcpkg` dir tree which uses that perticular toolchain?

By 'use', I mean vcpkg and all its packages should be compiled by that toolchain, and my projects which use vcpkg's toolchain_file '$vcpkg_home/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake' should all have that toolchain as $CC and build toolset?

Comment: Did you follow all the steps from the Quickstart? Did you get errors? Which steps worked, or didn't work? Please add these details to your question post!

Comment: edit: On my machine I have gcc 9.1 installed which is detected by vcpkg's bootstrap.sh and work fine;

Meanwhile, I built a toolchain for crossbuilding, which sits in $HOME/cross/x64_86-centos7-linux-gnu/

How can I setup another vcpkg dir tree which uses that perticular toolchain?

By 'use', I mean vcpkg and all its packages should be compiled by that toolchain, and my projects which use vcpkg's toolchain_file '$vcpkg_home/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake' should all have that toolchain as $CC and build toolset?

Comment: Please add all this information to your **question post**

Comment: Quick start: all steps to me work fine, compiled and runned a program with some vcpkg's packages;   Non-quickstart: problem is no cmake-ish xxx-toolchain.cmake in my cross compile toolchain dir tree to try as a -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE list item.

Comment: Not to mention that wish to compile vcpkg downloaded packages to install with that toolchain which I think is obviously a requirement to build projects.

Comment: To set up one can download a raspberry PI build toolset tarball to try with.

Answer (score 8):

You should write a [triplet file](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/blob/master/docs/users/triplets.md) that references your desired toolchain. Create a file `${VCPKG_ROOT}/triplets/x64-centos7` with content

```
set(VCPKG_TARGET_ARCHITECTURE x64)
set(VCPKG_CRT_LINKAGE dynamic)
set(VCPKG_LIBRARY_LINKAGE static)

set(VCPKG_CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)

set(VCPKG_CHAINLOAD_TOOLCHAIN_FILE /your/cmake/toolchain.cmake)
```

`/your/cmake/toolchain.cmake` beeing a [CMake toolchain](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html#cross-compiling-for-linux) like

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR x64)

set(CMAKE_SYSROOT /your/sysroot)

set(tools $HOME/cross/x64_86-centos7-linux-gnu/)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${tools}/bin/your-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${tools}/bin/your-g++)

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)
```

Comment: How would you to this to allow multiple users to collaborate on the project, with an easy onboarding process? Would you commit the triplet and toolchain files to the git repo? Would you list them as prerequisites for the user to install? I'm trying to figure out a viable process, with no success...